# change style of calendar component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I wanted to change my calendar component , from an old one to new one , they both exist on the website , but the new one isn't working, I want to make it work , when the user choose a date, it reacts with the website
this is my old one :
[image: old calendar component]

This is the Code :

```
import 'd3-transition';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {  setDatePrecision, nextDate, previousDate, loadWords, loadArticles } from "../redux/actions";

class DaySelector extends Component {
  state = {
    datePrecision: "day",
    selectedDate: new Date()
  };

  render() {
    const rthis = this.props;

    const prev = () => {
      rthis.previousDate();

      this.props.loadWords();

      this.props.loadArticles();
    };

    const next = () => {
      rthis.nextDate();
      this.props.loadWords();
      this.props.loadArticles();
    }

    const dayPrecision = () => {
      rthis.setDatePrecision("day");
      this.props.loadWords();
      this.props.loadArticles();
    }

    const monthPrecision = () => {
      rthis.setDatePrecision("month");
      this.props.loadWords();
      this.props.loadArticles();
    }
  
    const current_date = this.props.selectedDate;
    const datePrecision = this.props.datePrecision;
   
    const year = current_date.getFullYear();
    const month = current_date.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = current_date.getDate();

    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#day" onClick={dayPrecision}>day </a> 
        <a href="#month" onClick={monthPrecision}>month </a> 
        <a href="#prev" onClick={prev}>&lt;&lt;&lt;</a> 
        {datePrecision === "day" ? String(day).padStart(2, "0") + "/" : ""}{String(month).padStart(2, "0")}/{year} 
        <a href="#next" onClick={next}>&gt;&gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    selectedDate: state.wordsReducer.selectedDate,
    datePrecision: state.wordsReducer.datePrecision,
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setDatePrecision, nextDate, previousDate, loadWords, loadArticles })(DaySelector);
```

I want to replace it with this new Calendar :
[image: new calendar component]

this is the code of this component :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';

const MyCalendar = () => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const onChange = (date) => setDate(date);
    return (
        <div>
            <h5 className="card-title mb-0">Calendar</h5>

            <Calendar onChange={onChange} value={date} />

        </div>
    );
};

export default MyCalendar;
```

Those components are both on the website but I could not make it dynamically work,
I've install it from [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar)

Thank you !

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you , I think I did minimize my code .

Comment: I meant, it would help a lot if you reproduced the same problem in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I can not do that, I'm using API, which make it more difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing to pass the prop from onChange, try:

```js
 <Calendar onChange={(value, event) => onChange(value)} value={date} />
```

or try:

```js
 <Calendar onChange={(value, event) => setDate(value)} value={date} />
```